# Send data from android app to java application

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a university project in which I have to create an android application that uses token to authenticate a login request. As per my professors' request, the token is generated third party (in our case by the java application). The android app has to connect with java application to validate tokens. My idea to establish connection between those two apps was to use TCP sockets. While in theory that works, the issue that I have ran in practice is the address which the socket is going to be on.
For testing purposes, we can use local ip's however which address would we pick in real-world scenario? How would we establish connection between our java application and all of the android devices that have installed our apps?
How would we create a public socket server?
Thank you for your answers.

Comment: There are a few free hosting websites that can host your Java app (since it's a school project) like [heroku](https://www.heroku.com). Normally you would buy a host (which gives you a public IP) and then a domain name, which would be used to access it. In this case, since it's just an authentification service that runs on your java app, you might not need a domain name.

Comment: You can also set up a local server for testing purposes.